# How to connect user using fb messenger bot?

Tags: node.js, facebook, lambda, messenger, userid

Currently I'm trying to make a reminder bot where user can remind another user/ new user.

My approach to get the new user's userId is using share button, in order to make connection for the user and the new user, but when the user shares my bot to another user, it doesn't pass anything to lambda. 
So, the only way to get userId is when the new user hits the getting started button. That way, it's hard to know which are the users that are supposed to be connected.

What im trying to ask is how can I connect those users or is there another approach to solve this?

Comment: The purpose of the messenger platform is communication between a user and a page - so I very much doubt this use case would be approved by Facebook to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

According to facebook's policy , you can't get the userid without user's initial interaction that could be hitting the getting started button or something which is very disappointing.I have faced the same issue some time earlier.

Comment: That’s not “disappointing”, but necessary to prevent spammers from just pestering any arbitrary user with chat messages.

Comment: can we pass variable using this share button?